# XHR Upload Progress is 100% from the start

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying out the new XMLHTTPRequestUpload feature to upload some files to a php script, it mostly works fine, the upload starts, I get the finish response etc - but the progress doesn't seem to work.

Looking that the event.loaded value - In firefox I seem to get a random value between 0 and the file size; in Chrome (where I'm mostly working) I get the total file size, even though the readystate hasn't reached '4' and the Developer Tools window still shows the file to be loading?

Any ideas?

Heres my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        $('ajaxFeedbackDiv').innerHTML = event.loaded + ' / ' + event.total;
    }
}, false);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    if (event.target.readyState == 4) {
        updateFileList();
    }
};

xhr.open("POST", "_code/upload.php");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr(file);
```

Many thanks

Ben

Comment: Have you found any solution or workaround for the problem? I am currently experiencing the same, but it seems to be dependent on your network connection. It works as expected in one location, and jumps to 100% from the other.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.  Interestingly, it seems like this only happens for me when I'm running at localhost - when I deploy to our dev or prod servers, the loaded value comes back as one would expect.

Comment: XHR Upload Progress is 100% from the start only on localhost (I don't why), if you try to make a request to remote web server, or on a remote server, you will see sensible progress.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I also recently had some difficulty setting an event listener for XHR onprogress events.  I ended up implementing it as an anonymous function, which works beautifully:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt)
{
    if (evt.lengthComputable)
    {
        var percentComplete = parseInt((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
        console.log("Upload: " + percentComplete + "% complete")
    }
};
```

I stumbled across a *lot* of other gotchas along the way, though, so it's quite likely one of those was tripping up my event listener.  The only other difference between what you've got there and my setup is that I'm using xhr.sendAsBinary().

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar issue myself, where my event handler function for `progress` events on `XMLHttpRequest` was executed only once -- when the upload was complete.

The cause of the problem ended up being simple -- in Google Chrome (possibly other browsers too, I did not test), the `progress` event will only fire in succession if the upload had been running for a second or two. In other words, if your upload finishes quickly, then you'll likely just get one 100% `progress` event.

Here's an example of code whose `progress` event only fires once at 100% complete ( https://jsfiddle.net/qahs40r6/ ):

```
$.ajax({
  xhr: function()
  {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        console.log("Upload ", Math.round(percentComplete*100) + "% complete.");
      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/echo/json/",
  data: {json: JSON.stringify(new Array(20000))}
});
```

Console output:

```
Upload  100% complete.
```

But if you add an extra zero to the size of the array (increasing the payload size by a factor of 10 -- https://jsfiddle.net/qahs40r6/1/):

```
$.ajax({
  xhr: function()
  {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        console.log("Upload ", Math.round(percentComplete*100) + "% complete.");
      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/echo/json/",
  data: {json: JSON.stringify(new Array(200000))}
});
```

Then you get the normal progression of `progress` events:

```
Upload  8% complete.
Upload  9% complete.
Upload  19% complete.
Upload  39% complete.
Upload  50% complete.
Upload  81% complete.
Upload  85% complete.
Upload  89% complete.
Upload  100% complete.
```

This behavior depends upon how fast your Internet connection is, so your mileage will vary. For example, if you take the first example and use Chrome Developer Tools to slow your connection to a simulated "Slow 3G", then you will see the series of `progress` events.

Similarly, if you are developing locally and uploading data to a local web server, you'll likely never see `progress` events because the upload will finish instantly. This is likely what @brettjonesdev was seeing in localhost vs remote prod deployments.

Comment: I still have this issue when sending FormData, and throttling Chrome's upload speed. The upload will take up to a minute, and only emit an event at the end. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I have similar issue and I found reason. In my case the **troublemaker is antivirus (bitdefender)** on my PC. When I turn off bitdefender protection, the progress behaves exactly as it should.

Comment: Thanks John, I was searching everywhere... sometimes I hate BitDefender... just goes to show how much data it intercepts!

Comment: In our case, the Bitdefender Web Protection option caused the issue.