# XHR upload progress is 100% from start

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm uploading file to Node.JS server using `XMLHttpRequest`. I need to monitor progress, but I receive 100% almost right after firing uploading! But I see in the Network tab of the Google Chrome that uploading is in progress. I assume the problem lies in the CORS. Does anybody have any ideas how to solve this problem?

There are several such questions on Stack Overflow, but answers for them do not solve my problem at all. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352555/xhr-upload-progress-is-100-from-the-start) does not solve my problem also.

Simplified version of my code:

```js
function uploadFile(file, headers, endpoint) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', file.slice(), file.name);
  xhr.open('POST', endpoint, true);

  Object.entries(headers).forEach(([header, value]) => {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, value);
  });

  xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', ({ loaded, total, lengthComputable }) => {
    if (lengthComputable) {
      console.log(loaded / total * 100);
    }
  });

  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

I receive such response from server (JSON):

```js
{
  "indent_size": "4",
  "indent_char": " ",
  "max_preserve_newlines": "5",
  "preserve_newlines": true,
  "brace_style": "collapse",
  "space_before_conditional": true,
  "unescape_strings": false,
  "jslint_happy": false,
  "end_with_newline": false,
  "wrap_line_length": "0"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XHR Upload Progress is 100% from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352555/xhr-upload-progress-is-100-from-the-start)

Comment: @GrafiCode No, unfortunately. I explored all such questions on StackOverflow and other forums. No answers and even hints were found.

Comment: How big is the file you're uploading? I tested your code verbatim on localhost, picked a 77MB file and got about a dozen log lines starting from `8.17...`. Which means that your code probably works but not like you expect it to.

Comment: @ChrisG Last time I tested it on file that has 5.5 MB. I got "3" and "100" and see in the "Network" it is still uploading. Can this problem be caused by Node.JS server?

Comment: That's possible, yes; what is the server sending back as response?

Comment: @ChrisG I added server response snippet to the question.

Comment: Are you positive it is still uploading? If that server runs on your own computer, 5.5 MB won't take more than a second, and you are getting the reply, which afaik means the request i.e. upload has finished.

Comment: @ChrisG I'm uploading file to the remote server. Are there any ways to check uploading really finished? In case of 5.5 MB file I have big gap (tens of seconds) between 100% and XHR completion.